# Problem with CH340 drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 (ESP8266 programming)

Tags: kernel, serial-port

On current kernel in Ubuntu 20.04.3 there is problem using boards with CH340 (nodeMCU v3, Wemos). Serial communication with board is OK, just programming is not possible. It is due to DTR/DTS lines are used to reset ESP8266, and that seems to be failing.

Problem is similar (the same?) like described here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214131

Programming CH340 board is not possible: "/dev/ttyUSB0 failed to connect: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header"

Last working kernel for me was 5.4.0-86. Is there a solution for that other than keeping old kernel?

Comment: Please check your serial, type " ls -l /dev/tty* "

Comment: Communication via Serial is OK. Problem is with DTS/DTR lines used by boards to control reset and boot mode (ESP8266 needs to be entered into program mode on boot and this lines are used to control reset/GPIO's required to be in proper state to start programming).
Programmed board communicates via Serial with computer without any problems.

Comment: Do you have permissions to RW /dev/ttyUSB0 ? , Did you try it with Blink example?

Comment: Probably this is a wires problem, Probably this is a driver problem, I don't think this is a kernel problem, try to use double-reset trick. try this one https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/56423/48274